# webpack doesnt work for react. ERROR Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, darwin

I need to run webpack -w for React project (javascript).
It worked fine, but then after trying to install a virtual environment for python on windows(not sure if this is related or coincidence), webpack stopped working.
In the git terminal it throws the following errors:

1. I think the key is in terminal error 2:
   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: **Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})**

I think its related to the operating system part of the error. 
Does anyone know how I can get webpack to run again? How I can get the expected OS to be correct?

[terminal error for "HelloDiv" exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXE5C.png)
[package.json and webpack config for "Hello Div"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8KBI.png)

Comment: Looks like you're getting a json parsing issue in your package.json

Comment: you may have an extra comma or a missing comma or some other formatting issue in your package.json. Would you mind posting the contents?

Comment: the skipping optional dependency is normal for windows platform fsevents seems to be for OSX.

Comment: post your `package.json` file here

Comment: Yeah the skipping optional dependency thing is fine (fsevents is OSX only) so it must be another part of your webpack config. Can you post it for us?

Comment: I posted a screenshot of the package.json and webpack.config.js @IlanHasanov

Comment: `module.exports = { 
  entry: "./app/app.js", 
  output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          // These are the specific transformations we'll be using. 
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}` @BenHare

Comment: Sorry is that a screenshot of the Users\test\Desktop\package.json? Because that's where the error is, and in the screenshot it seems like it's one from your project directory, not that one.

Comment: All images terminal error, package,json and webpack.config should now be from the same directory/class exercise "Hello Div".  Sorry @BenHare, hopefully this clears things up, because otherwise I'm confused about where you think the error is.

Comment: Thanks @BenHare , you were right. I had never run into a problem where the error was outside the directory being worked on.  There was a random package.json on my desktop (like your comment pointed out).  Turns out the moral of the story is - read carefully and trust errors